# VueJs with google maps API TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: google-maps, vue.js, google-maps-api-3, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm following this tutorial (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/practical-use-of-scoped-slots.html#3-Expose-google-and-map-properties-to-the-parent-component-by-adding-a-scoped-slot) and I've ran into a circular import issue in my map loader component.

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Pi'
    |     property 'gm_bindings_' -> object with constructor 'Object'
    |     property 'controlSize' -> object with constructor 'Object'
    |     ...
    |     property 'controlSize' -> object with constructor 'Object'
    --- property 're' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
```

Here is the code, I'm really not sure where this is coming from and how i can go about fixing it.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class='google-map' ref='googleMap'></div>
    <template v-if="Boolean(this.google) && Boolean(this.map) ">
      <slot
        :google="google"
        :map="map"
      />
    </template>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import GoogleMapsApiLoader from 'google-maps-api-loader';

export default {
  name: 'GmapLoader',
  props: {
    mapConfig: Object,
    apiKey: String,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      google: null,
      map: null,
    };
  },
  async mounted() {
    const googleMapsApi = await GoogleMapsApiLoader({
      apiKey: this.apiKey,
    });
    this.google = googleMapsApi;
    this.initMap();
  },
  methods: {
    initMap() {
      const mapContainer = this.$refs.googleMap;
      this.map = new this.google.maps.Map(mapContainer, this.mapConfig);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

If needed i can also post in the parent component that is loading this but i believe that has nothing to do with the issue. The chrome debugger says the issue is coming from the `mounted` hook so i have a feeling it has something to do with the `googleMap` ref object being converted to json.